# Javascript MarkActive Function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement a function "markActive", which, when given a list of objects and an id, returns the same list, but with the corresponding object marked active, like for example,

```
var list = [
           { id: 1, active: false },
           { id: 2, active: false },
           { id: 3, active: true  },
           { id: 4, active: false }
         ];
```

when function is called

```
markActive(list, 2);
```

should Return:

```
[
{ id: 1, active: false },
{ id: 2, active: true  },
{ id: 3, active: false },
{ id: 4, active: false }
]
```

i tried many loops but everytime i was getting undefined, 
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could iterate the array and set `active` with a check of the `id`.

```js
function markActive(array, id) {
    array.forEach(function (o) {
        o.active = o.id === id;
    });
    return list;
}

var list = [{ id: 1, active: false }, { id: 2, active: false }, { id: 3, active: true }, { id: 4, active: false }];

console.log(markActive(list, 2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array#forEach`

```js
var list = [{
  id: 1,
  active: false
}, {
  id: 2,
  active: false
}, {
  id: 3,
  active: true
}, {
  id: 4,
  active: false
}];

function markActive(list, id) {
  list.forEach(function(el) {
    if (el.id == id) {
      el.active = true;
    } else {
      el.active = false;
    }
  });
}
markActive(list, 2);
console.log(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set everything to inactive unless the id should be set to active then do that

```
function markActive(list, item) {
    list.forEach(function(element) {
    if (element.active) {
            element.active = false;
        }
    if (element.id === item) {
    console.log(item)
        element.active = true;
    }
  })
}
```